# Chartjs react horizontal bar chart change y axis labels to images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

In this chart I want to replace the text labels "January", "February", etc. with images:

[image]

How can I do this with Chart.js and React chart js 2?
I cannot see this document in the documentation.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/hopeful-benji-mlv429?workspaceId=d572ab8b-8ff5-4e03-b4cc-0bc91a3479d7&embed=1&file=%2FApp.tsx&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsv6sayk00082v6llovuig4q%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsv6sayj00032v6ldgf4t3vj%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsv6sayj00052v6l2t14siwu%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsv6sayj00072v6lplspywjy%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsv6sayj00032v6ldgf4t3vj%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsv6sayj00032v6ldgf4t3vj%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvnt6u9002w2v6mf4iej07i%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A62%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A2%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A65%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A1%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsvnt6u9002w2v6mf4iej07i%2522%257D%252C%2522clsv6sayj00072v6lplspywjy%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsv6sayj00062v6lwp275yua%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsv6sayj00072v6lplspywjy%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsv6sayj00062v6lwp275yua%2522%257D%252C%2522clsv6sayj00052v6l2t14siwu%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsv6sayj00042v6l8ghpoluw%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsv6sayj00052v6l2t14siwu%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsv6sayj00042v6l8ghpoluw%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write months on bars you can use ChartDataLabels plugins and formatter.

```
 plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    options: {
        indexAxis: "y",
        plugins: {
          datalabels: {
            color: "#fff",
            anchor: "center",
            align: "center",
            font: {
              size: 16,
            },
            formatter: function (value, context) {
              return months[context.dataIndex];
            },
          },
        },
      },
```

this will you give something like this

[months on text label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkLx1.png)